# Optional parameter in @PathParam annotation

Tags: java, rest, jersey

We are facing issue related with making a path parameter optional.

original URL `/expire/{token}`

What we are trying to do is have the same service work for the URL's below.

```
   1. /expire/{token}
   2. /expire

Ex:- @Path("/expire/{token}")
```

We have already applied other solutions from SO,but no luck so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logically, it doesn't seem to make sense to have it optional. Your URI should handle the type of request it's supposed to do. But, I came across a post to make the `@PathParam` to be optional with a small hack using regular expressions.

http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters/

I would go with having separate endpoint method in Controller where it can pass the call to your services with optional parameter.

Comment: It does make sense according to REST! /expire/{token}
   2. /expire .. can give a list of tokens

Answer (score 18):

What about adding another method annotated with only:

```
@Path("/expire")
```

And let this method pass a null value into the original method.

Answer (score 1):

We can use regular expressions,

```
"@Path("/add/{a:([0-9.]*)}/{b:([0-9.]*)}{p:/?}{c:([0-9.]*)}")"
```

here path can be

```
add/2/3
add/2/3/4
```

my case I am using regular expressions for allowing only numbers